# Azure Powershell Template: return Boolean if all resource provisioned successfully?

Tags: powershell, azure, templates

I invoke PowerShell's `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet to spin up a plethora of Azure resources according to my JSON Template.
But, often either the MongoDB or Redis VM fail to provision the first time, and I run the command again, and the provision succeeds.

Where can I programmatically know whether my deployment succeeded for *all resources*, and use this Boolean in a while loop to keep deploying until all resources have provisioned successfully?  The cmdlet above does return an object but I haven't been able to find an indicator of success of provisioning.

Something along the lines of:

```
While ($didNotSucceed) {
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile <FileName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment bla-bla-bla
if ($result.ProvisioningState -eq "Failed") {
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment bla-bla-bla
}
```

Resource group deployment have `ProvisioningState` property which has the provisioning state of the deployment (surprisingly). It is `Failed` or `Succeeded` (I haven't seen other statuses).

Also, here's what I've been using with my Jenkins build job:

```
try { $deploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment @parameters }
catch { Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Force; $error; $_; exit 1 }
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation to your post that talks about how the code works. This allows new developers to understand what the code does.

Comment: There's almost nothing to explain. But if you insist.

Comment: The code was enough to solve my own question, but the explanation doesn't hurt. Thanks.